# How is a measurement on an electron done?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

There are two ways how to change a direction of a qubit - one with Larmor precession, another with a measurement. I am not sure about the measurement one.

Let's say I have an electron with spin pointing in z axis direction. I let it through beamsplitter oriented in y axis direction (Stern-Gerlach aparatus with inhomogenic magnetic field in y axis direction). So now I have an electron in superposition between up and down. How do I make it official - that it has only one of the possible positions (break the superposition), while not disrupting the electron beam?

Comment: The electron is charged and has a magnetic moment, so you can use both electrostatic and magnetic probes. If it has high enough energy you can run it trough a thin scintillator and it won't be absorbed etc.. As long as your electron has a couple of keV of kinetic energy it's pretty easy to detect.

Comment: I'm confused. First your qubit is spin up in the z direction, then you pass it through a Stern-Gerlach oriented in the y direction. This causes the beam to split into two beams, one which is spin +y the other which is spin -y. What is the question? Do you want to further split each of those beams by a Stern-Gerlach oriented in the z direction?